# Is the use of for in this statement correct: "I would like for you to get me that pen"?

Tags: prepositions

I have just had a debate with a  colleague related to the use of "for" in a sentence. I would therefore request correction/guidance here: Is the use of **for** in these statements correct: "I would like for you to get me that pen"; I would like for you to read me those words"?

Comment: It's grammatically correct.

Comment: It's grammatically correct but often deleted in speech. Do a search on prepositions for more information.

Comment: It is grammatically correct but would not usually be used for such a small thing as a pen. The contextual use is usually for "grander" things: Why? Because this way of saying it implies a broader discussion. If would like for you to read me those words and then tell me what you think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["To like for somebody/something to be something" vs. "to like somebody/something to be something"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75720/to-like-for-somebody-something-to-be-something-vs-to-like-somebody-something)